# Finding an index in an array of objects with 3 possible outcomes

Tags: javascript, search

`currentUserPosts` will have a post object with an `id` that either matches a `tempId`, an `Id`, or nothing.

If there's a `tempId` match there won't be an `id` match and vice versa.

This code works but there's something about it I don't like. How can it be refactored?

```
let postIndex;
postIndex = currentUserPosts.findIndex(post => post.id === upsertParams.tempId);
if (postIndex === -1) {
  postIndex = currentUserPosts.findIndex(post => post.id === upsertParams.id);
}
if (postIndex === -1) {
  currentUserPosts.push(upsertParams);
} else {
  currentUserPosts[postIndex] = upsertParams;
}
```

Complete function:

```
const upsertIntoApolloCache = (upsertParams) => {
  try {
    const data = client.readQuery({
      query: USER_POSTS_QUERY,
    });
    const currentUserPosts = data.currentUser.posts;

    const postIndex = currentUserPosts.findIndex(
      post => post.id === upsertParams.tempId || post.id === upsertParams.id
    );
    if (postIndex === -1) {
      currentUserPosts.push(upsertParams);
    } else {
      currentUserPosts[postIndex] = upsertParams;
    }

    client.writeQuery({
      query: USER_POSTS_QUERY,
      data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('!!ERROR in upsertIntoApolloCache!!', error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the two conditions for finding into a single `||` condition, since the `post.id` can match only one of `tempId` or `id`.

```
let postIndex = currentUserPosts.findIndex(post => {
  return post.id === upsertParams.id || post.id === upsertParams.tempId
});

if (postIndex === -1) {
  currentUserPosts.push(upsertParams);
} else {
  currentUserPosts[postIndex] = upsertParams;
}
```

You could, if possible, also change the `currentUserPosts` from array to a dictionary mapping your `post.id` to the `post` itself. This entirely depends on your further usage of the `currentUserPosts` across application.

---

Based on updated question content:

```
let currentUserPosts = {}
for (let post of data.currentUser.posts) {
  currentUserPosts[post.id] = post
}
```

This way, you'd only have to check against `id` using [the `in`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/in) operation:

```
let newId = upsertParams.id || upsertParams.tempId
if (newId in currentUserPosts)
  // do unspeakable things
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are missing a `return` in your findIndex method.

Comment: Ha!! That was an easy one.  Thanks @hjpotter92!
Regarding your second suggestion. Don't completely understand what you're getting at.  I'll update my questions with the full function so you can see.  It probably doesn't matter because I don't have control of the structure.  It's a cache object provided by Apollo.